# Mongodb taking too much time to find the record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongodb on localhost, in database I have 90 million records. When I search for any record via `db.emails.find({"name":"example"})`, it is taking too long to get result. Is there any way I can increase speed of mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) for `name` field

```
db.emails.createIndex( { name: 1} )
```

If you don't have index for field, then mongodb must perform a *collection scan* when executing query, i.e. scan every document in collection to check value of `name` field that match your query. This index on other hand stores only ordered values of `name` field which can be checked quickly.

There is limit for index key. Totals size of index entry must be less than 1024 bytes. But you can use text index if you want to search queries on string content:

```
db.emails.createIndex( { name: "text"} )
```

Also if you want to search for exact match, then you can use hashed index:

```
db.emails.createIndex( { name: "hashed" })
```

Comment: I careated index using same function, got this error
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing  5452 { : \"Bandaancha39escalones.es4everexiliados.creatuforo.com7artpictures.com7peliculas.coma3magazine.comadictasalcibersexo.comaestrada.netagente69.comanimeid...\" }",
        "code" : 17280,
        "codeName" : "KeyTooLong"
}

Comment: It is very fast for normal search, but when I am performing like query on it, it is taking much time.
Any suggestion to improve speed of like query.
Query Example: db.web_tech.find({url:/.*sa.*/}).count()

Answer (score 0):

Usually to speedup mongodb queries, what one can do is to prepare a composed index.

In your case, since it is email addresses, what I would suggest you to do is to put the mail as the id and perform search using regular expressions that are case insensitive. For example if you want everyone that has gmail accounts, you could perform a search like

`db.users.find({_id:/@gmail.com/})`

I believe this would speedup your code a lot